# Javascript Slideshow sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

Today I am trying to create an image slideshow in which there are several effects of interest taking place.

What I am trying to achieve can be found at this link:
http://themes.jozoor.com/invention/white/index.html. Notice when you cycle through the slideshow on the homepage, the picture and other elements slide into place.

Comment: in SO, asking a question with no code is like going to a strip club with no stippers ... show us some code!

Comment: Why does one need to provide code in this circumstance? I simply want some theory or teaching on how something like this works, I see no reason why providing code will help YOU deliver some knowledge to me? Especially since I didnt ask for existing code to be fixed, delivered or improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the Flexslider and add the animations by themselves.
If you view the [code](http://themes.jozoor.com/invention/white/js/custom.js) you will find

```
e(".flexslider").flexslider({
    animation:         "fade",
    animationLoop:     true,
    slideshow:         true,
    slideshowSpeed:    6e3,
    animationSpeed:    800,
    pauseOnHover:      true,
    pauseOnAction:     true,
    controlNav:        false,
    directionNav:      true,
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
    start:             function(t)
    {
        var n = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide h2").data("toptitle");
        var r = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide .item").data("topimage");
        var i = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide p").data("bottomtext");
        var s = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide .links").data("bottomlinks");
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".item").css({top: r});
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".item").animate({right: "0", opacity: "1"}, 1e3);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("h2").animate({left: "0", top: n, opacity: "1"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("p").animate({left: "0", bottom: i, opacity: "1"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".links").animate({left: "0", bottom: s, opacity: "1"}, 1800);
        t.removeClass("loading")
    },
    before:            function(t)
    {
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".item").animate({
            right:   "-100%",
            opacity: "0"
        }, 1e3);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("h2").animate({left: "0", top: "-100%", opacity: "0"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("p").animate({left: "0", bottom: "-50%", opacity: "0"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".links").animate({
            left:    "0",
            bottom:  "-100%",
            opacity: "0"
        }, 1800)
    },
    after:             function(t)
    {
        var n = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide h2").data("toptitle");
        var r = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide .item").data("topimage");
        var i = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide p").data("bottomtext");
        var s = e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide .links").data("bottomlinks");
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".item").css({top: r});
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".item").animate({right: "0", opacity: "1"}, 1e3);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("h2").animate({left: "0", top: n, opacity: "1"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find("p").animate({left: "0", bottom: i, opacity: "1"}, 1500);
        e(".slider-1 .flex-active-slide").find(".links").animate({left: "0", bottom: s, opacity: "1"}, 1800)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Layer slider pal. If you dont want to start developing the plugin once again then just buy the layer slider. Search google with layerslider.

Slider like these are not easy to develop. If you you have already started then show us some code, otherwise buy the existing one

Comment: Kaustav, thanks for that. At least now I know the terminology associated with this effect. I can no try and develop my own or buy one.